# Entity Framework query with ToList().Last() in Where()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have to get records from database which last of `OrderStatus` is `Registered`. This is how I try to find those records

```
    List<Order> orders = db.Orders
        .Include("OrderStatuses")
        .Where(x => x.OrderStatuses.ToList().Last().Status == StatusOrder.Registered)
        .ToList();
```

but I get exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Lomax.Models.OrderStatus
>   LastOrderStatus'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there any way not getting all `Orders` from db first and then looking for those which last `OrderStatus` is which I want? Or it doesn't matter (in speed)?

Order class:

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        (...)
        public virtual ICollection<OrderStatus> OrderStatuses { get; set; }
    }
```

OrderStatus class:

```
public class OrderStatus
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Enumerates.StatusOrder Status { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Order")]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do not call `ToList()` *everywhere*. Call it only where it's required - it allocates memory: consumes memory and more CPU, every time.

Comment: I don't know your data struct but you can probably simplify this by starting at the order status table e.g db.OrderStatuses.Where(x => x.Status == StatusOrder.Registered).Select(x => x.Order)

Comment: @johnny5 it takes all `Orders` where any of `StatusOrder` is `Registered`. After `Registered` there can be `Cancelled` status or any other which I don't want to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to entity does not support .Last(). 
you can use orderby() and take() instead

```
 List<Order> orders = db.Orders
        .Include("OrderStatuses")
        .Where(x => x.OrderStatuses.OrderByDescending(q => q.YourCol).First().Status == StatusOrder.Registered)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: How do you determine which OrderStatus is "last"?

Comment: I think by default the primary key or first column is order by, order. You can check the query by removing ToList() to see which column is at the first.

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad, No SQL has no default order unless specified

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft by add time.

Comment: @ArashGhasemiRad I think that's correct, ordering by Date and checking if first status is which I want gives me list of correct orders. Many thanks.

Comment: What about `.Reverse()`?